Analyzing Quantization Effects on DSP Algorithms
This post is a continuation of my other post titled: Simulating ADC Effects on DSP Algorithm with Fixed-Point Representation.
I expect a rf signals which is around -50dBm. After it is received, it will undergo mixing and other analog processing and the expected output volt should be between -1.8V to 1.8V (input voltage range of the adc).
Now, i have an idea of the signals i will be receiving, simulated it in GNU radio and tested my algorithm. The data type used is complex64 and the amplitude range of the generated signal is 389 to -363. The interference is 10dB stronger than the desired signals.
My approach in converting it to fixed point:
$$ \mu = \frac{max(x(nT)) + min(x(nT))}{2} = \frac{389-363}{2} = 13$$
$$ x(nT) = x(nT) - \mu$$
this will give me the amplitude range between 376 to -376.
Dividing by 376,
$$ x(nT) = \frac{x(nT)}{376}, \quad -1V \leq x(nT) \leq 1V $$
To account for clipping and non-linearities of adc, $x$dB is backed off from the peak value.
$$ V_p = 1V \times 10^{-x/20} V $$
$$ x(nT) = x(nT)\times V_p $$
For fixed point conversion and to account for clipping (credit to @dan boschen (previous post)),
$$ x[n] = \lfloor x(nT)\times \frac{(2^{ENOB-1})}{Vp} \rfloor \ \text{counts}$$
$$\text{if } x[n] < -2^{ENOB-1}, x[n] = -2^{ENOB-1}$$
$$\text{ if } x[n] > 2^{ENOB-1}-1, x[n] = 2^{ENOB-1} -1$$
The main objective is to understand how quantization affects my algorithm, to determine the maximum interference-to-signal ratio that can be tolerated before quantization noise begins to impact the desired signal and what to expect out of FPGA. I am aware i am assuming an ideal ADC, but i am hoping this will give me some idea on what i want.
I'm new to all this and not sure how accurate I am with my steps, detailed explanation is appreciated.
Here's the adc i am considering https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD9650.pdf

I could provide a shorter answer here but it wouldn't be able address all the considerations needed. I'm not sure if you had checked out the online course starting later this month, but in that I literally spend hours going through this specific example with all the considerations related to this question - I'm confident you'd get a lot out of it so please consider signing up (the early registration discount is ending soon). It's "DSP for Software Radio" offered through dsprelated.com (see https://www.dsprelated.com/courses ).

It was answering a different question about fixed-point processing, but in this answer I discuss how to analytically look at quantization error done when word length reduction occurs in the computation of an algorithm.  With fixed-point, it's pretty simple.  With floating-point it's a bit more complicated because of the scaling.

@DanBoschen, I took a look at your course, and while it is definitely appealing, I can't afford it. But i will reconsider in the future.

@rrpv thanks for letting me know- being active here is definitely the good “free” option given the skills and backgrounds of everyone here. It just can’t replace the depth of a full course but is perfect for short Q&A with tighter focus on specific well defined problems. Glad to have you here!

You may be overthinking this.
Step 1: optimize the SNR at the ADC

-1.8V to 1.8V (input voltage range of the adc).

According to the data sheet the input voltage range 2.7Vpp, that means you need to restrict yourself to -1.35V to 1.35V. You probably want maybe 1 dB or of headroom so you you should plan for maybe -1.2V to +1.2V.
Step 2: SNR analysis
In order to map your model to the actual hardware you need to adjust a scale factor. Since your model has a peak of 389 (in whatever units) and you want your peak voltage at the ADC to be 1.2V, you should scale accordingly
$$ 389 \text{Simulink Units} = 1.2V = -1dBdFS = 14602 \text{integer} = 0.89125 \text{fractional} $$
I would NOT take out the mean and try to make everything symmetric. You want to maintain 0=0 through the entire signal and processing chain.
Your ADC has an SNR of about 82 dB (depending on exact model and frequency) for a full scale sine wave. Since we added 1dB of headroom, that comes down to 81 dB. If your signal is not a sine wave you also need to adjust for the crest factor of the signal. If it has a crest factor of, say, 10dB, your SNR drops to 71dB (since a sine wave has a crest factor of 3dB). Since your signal sits 40dB below the interferer, that means your quantization noise sits about 31 dB below our signal which isn't all that much.
Whatever processing you do will also add numerical noise. If you keep everything in 16 bits and the processing is fairly "mild" that shouldn't be a problem. The  numerical rounding error for 16 bit is around -98dBdFS per operation which is significantly lower than your quantization noise. So you have about 10 operations before this starts to become noticeable. If that is a problem you can always throw more bits on it on an FPGA.

The short answer is ultimately for a receiver we are concerned about the ability to maintain a minimum SNR (as given by the particular waveform being used, this is often quantified as EVM or correlation coefficient, both of which we can relate directly to SNR), over a range of operating conditions which includes jamming immunity, range of transmit power levels and distances between transmitter and receiver, and gain variations over the operating channel including the receiver components themselves. All this comes down to a careful system design that factors in and makes trades on all of these conditions and considers the receiver architecture in front of the ADC (most notably gain control implementation, linearity of components, phase noise, and filtering). Part of that system trade will be which receiver functions will be done digitally and which will be done in the analog which ultimately leads to a requirement for ADC dynamic range to meet all of those objectives. The dynamic range will extend to minimum discernable signal, where if the input signal power level were to decrease any lower, the minimum SNR based on the waveform requirements itself would not be met (for example ~ 20 dB for 16-QAM at a particular minimum acceptable error rate). The quantization noise floor from the ADC is part of the overall noise budget that leads to a receiver Noise Figure metric. If we add more overall gain from the front end to increase the signal level under our weakest signal condition, then thermal noise plus electronics noise prior to the ADC input will dominate, minimizing the effects of quantization noise. HOWEVER, this then means we will not have an ability to handle a stronger signal under the same conditions so the overall dynamic range suffers (dynamic range is between weakest signal condition and strongest signal condition; where strongest signal also includes adjacent channel interference and jammers).
As I mentioned in the comments under the question, I go through this very scenario in much greater detail in my "DSP for SW Radio" course (that is starting very soon at dsprelated.com/courses) where each of these considerations can be elaborated on much more than I am able to do here with a short Q&A forum - but I did want to provide further insight into the considerations that would be made, and how ultimately an ADC with a greater SNR (as given by the estimator 6.02 dB/bit + 1.76 dB) allows for more dynamic range overall in the digital portion of the receiver design, and therefore allows for doing receiver processing digitally rather than in the analog - leading to greater flexibility and reconfigurability overall.
Also see this prior DSP.SE response where I have further detailed some of the considerations that I am listing above.
